# How much does 24 hours of a large instance on ec2 cost?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

I'm trying to get a gist of how much a large ec2 instant ( 64bit 4GB RAM ) would cost, without the bandwidth & incoming/outgoing requests.

If i were to start an instant and keep it running for a day, how much would it cost me ?

Comment: You've tried their calculator - http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html ?

Comment: One web search and a click later: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

Answer (score 1):

$8.16 *ix, $11.52 Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want a fixed price instance, in which case the current daily rate is as Matthew says, or if you're prepared to use a [spot priced instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/), where you bid a maximum price and get a running instance as long as Amazon's spot price for that instance type (which is based on supply and demand) stays below your bid.  The price for a large spot priced instance right now is 12.5c / hr for UNIX/Linux and 20.7c/hr for Windows, which gives you $3/day Linux/UNIX or $4.97/day Windows.

You could also use a [reserved instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/), where you pay an up front fee and then get a reduced hourly rate for a fixed period.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew said.

See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing